# Nanoc & ss social circle

Tags: ruby, nanoc

I have a problem using ss social circle web fonts.

In my rules I have:

```
compile '/assets/webfonts/*/' do
end

route '/assets/webfonts/*' do
end
```

in the web fonts folder I have:

```
ss-social-circle.css   ss-social-circle.svg  ss-social-circle.woff
ss-social-circle.eot*  ss-social-circle.ttf  ss-social.js
```

This gives me following error:

```
RuntimeError: Found 5 content files for content/assets/webfonts/ss-social-circle; expected 0 or 1
```

I'm not sure how to mitigate this problem in `nanoc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions as far as nanoc 3.x are concerned. Both solutions are described in detail on the [nanoc Troubleshooting page](http://nanoc.ws/docs/troubleshooting/#error-found-3-content-files-for-x-expected-0-or-1). In short, either rename files, or use the static data source.

Since this is such a common problem, this problem is being tackled in nanoc 4.

Answer (score 0):

It seams this is not possible in `nanoc`until the new version 4 comes out :( But I can split it in different folders.